# iTunes API how to get entity music?

Tags: javascript, api, itunes

I have a little problem.
I need to use the iTunes Api to get music.
In this case, I want to find music for Ed Sheeran, so I use:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=Ed+Sheeran&entity=music
```

However, I get the following error:

> errorMessage: "Invalid value(s) for key(s): [resultEntity]"

In the documentation the value `music` is correct, so my question is: why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is with `entity=music` as `music` is not a valid entity. The `entity` component of the URL is used to specify what your search should return back. It can take different values such as `musicArtist`, `musicTrack`, `album`, `song` etc...

You can find a full list of different entity types in iTune's API [documentation](https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/)

So, if you're after a list of songs, your URL should be like so:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=Ed+Sheeran&entity=song
```